# Android App Development: Handling Screen Orientation Changes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have run into a problem with handling screen orientation changes (For example: portrait to landscape). I'm developing a flashlight app which has a toggle button that turns the LED light on or off on the person's phone. I set up my onPause() method to kill the app like so:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         finish();
    }
```

This is because if I was to open the app and then go something else (like open youtube) and then come back and press the button again it crashes. But because of this "finish();" thing I can't handle screen orientation changes because apparently when it switches orientation it calls the onPause() method which finishes!

SO my question is...how do I do both? I want to be able to fix the crash problem but also not have it crash when the screen orientation changes. I'm not asking for code (although it would be helpful) just some insight from a new set of eyes.

I thought about using an "if" statement...would this work?

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: how about Override the `onBackPress` and finish there without the need to finish it in `onPause()`

Comment: @Coderji - Wouldn't that only work if the back button was pressed and not the home or recent (if on a nexus device) buttons?

Comment: no, I dont think it will work for home button. mmm you can use if statement within the onPause() but what can the statement be. you can use `OrientationListner` to detect if it will change or not.. and as soon as it will change assign a number to a variable and put it as if statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the screen orientation changes, the activity will do onPause(), onStop() and onCreate() again. If you don't want your activity do onPause when the orientation changes, try this:

1. In your manifest.xml, add android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" for your activity like:

   ```
   <activity android:name=".yourname"
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
   </activity>
   ```
2. In your activity, override this method:

   ```
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   }
   ```

But my advice is not to use `finish()` in `onPause()`, the system can handle the lifecycle just fine. If you want to finish your activity when the home or back button pressed, try to override `onBackPress()` and `onUserLeaveHint()`, these two method can catch back and home button pressed, and add `finish()` in these two method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works great! The onPause() method doesn't finish but the onBackPress() and the onUserLeaveHint() methods finish. Thank you very much.