# Common button must clear back stack in Android application

Tags: android, stack, fragment, back

The layout of my Android application is divided into a top bar (a `RelativeLayout`) and another `LinearLayout` where fragments are loaded and changed.
This is an overview:
[image: Overview]

When the application is started the first *Main screen* is shown and the menu fragments are loaded inside the inferior layout. Pressing on each of the 3 buttons will change the fragment but the top bar will always be the same, as it stays outside the fragment.

- If I press button number **1** after one of the fragments (2, 3, 4) has been loaded, the menu fragment must be shown and the back stack must be cleared so if I press the back button the application is closed.
- If I press the back button when I am viewing fragments 2, 3 or 4 I must go back to the menu fragment, too.
- If on fragment 4 I click the *Go to 3* button, I will go to fragment 3. Here, if I press back, I must go to fragment 4 but if I click on button **1** I must go to the menu, where if I press back button the application is closed.

Basically, each time I get to the menu fragment the stack must be cleared and this is what I don't know how to do.

In first place, this is how I change the fragments:

```
// Importing and stuff ...
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

    private int CurrentFragment = 0;

    // onCreate
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Among other things I set up the event for the Button 1
        Button1.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (CurrentFragment != 0) showFragment(0);
            }
        }
    );
    }

    // This is what happens when pressing the back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 && CurrentFragment != 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Fragment CurrentFrag = fm.findFragmentById(R.layout.menu);
            if (CurrentFrag != null) ft.remove(CurrentFrag);
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            this.finish();
        }
    }

    // This method will show the specified fragment 
    public void showFragment(int fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        String ftag = "menu";
        Fragment fi;
        switch (fragment) {
            case 0:
                fi = Fragment1.newInstance();
                ftag = "menu";
            break;
            case 1:
                fi = Fragment2.newInstance();
                ftag = "frag2";
            break;
            case 2:
                fi = Fragment3.newInstance();
                ftag = "frag3";
            break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContentLayout, fi);
        // If this is not the menu fragment add it to the back stack
        if (fragment != 0) ft.addToBackStack(ftag);
        ft.commit();
        CurrentFragment = fragment;
    }
}
```

Inside each one's of the fragment's classes this is what I have:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        Fragment1 NewFragment = new Fragment1();
        return NewFragment ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View FragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, new RelativeLayout(Main.MainContext));
        FragmentView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return FragmentView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way that work for me is to do this:

```
   fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Insert this code into the onActivityCreated() of your menu fragment, so each time you go there, the backstack will be cleared.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I used `popBackStack` each time the common button **1** is pressed and before the fragment is changed.

Comment: I realized that now, when I rotate the phone, the view is always reset to the initial screen (like the application is being re-started).

Comment: When you change orientation, the activity is destroyed and recreated. Basically, you have to handle orientation changes, overriding onNewConfiguration(). See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087033/android-app-development-handling-screen-orientation-changes

Comment: You mean `onConfigurationChanged`, I suppose. Thanks